# Download file from encrypted s3 bucket in CloudFormation::Init - files step

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

How can I read a file from a kms server side encrypted S3 bucket in the files step of a CloudFormation::Init resource? The below example stack works if the S3 bucket doesn't any encryption. but fails with the error shown below for an encyrpted bucket.

[Stack Example](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/S3Bucket_SourceAuth.template)

Error:

Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.

Stripped down template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Resources" : {
    "ProcessingMachine1" : {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
          "S3AccessCreds": {
            "type" : "S3",
            "accessKeyId" : "some-key",
            "secretKey" : "some-secret",
            "buckets" : [ "bucket-name" ]
          }
        },
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
          "config": {
            "files": {
              "path-to-file": {
                "source": "https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/file-name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried running aws cli commands under user data section ? `"UserData": { "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "\n",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash -vxe",  aws s3 cp and followed by aws s3 decrypt `.  I have not tried, you can see if it works, I was able to copy the uncrypted file without using CFT Init section.